# Does this statement of Chinna jeeyar have a scriptural basis?

Tags: shiva, ramayana

From [website of Chinna Jeeyar](https://chinnajeeyar.guru/chinnajeeyar/is-it-true-that-worshipping-ramakrishna-bring-difficulties-and-worshipping-siva-would-bring-happiness-and-properity/),

> Lord Siva also several occasions sought the help of these incarnations. You can see that in Sri Ramayana, after the killing of Ravana. All the devathas appeared before Rama and one among was Lord Siva, who praised Srirama as the saviour of the wise and punisher of wicked.

Does this statement of Chinna jeeyar have a scriptural basis?

Comment: See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Use markdown for formatting questions and answers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a scriptural reference from the Ramayana. In fact, Chinna Jeeyar Swami has himself given the reference where to find. Swamiji said "After killing Ravana", so it is found in the Yuddha Kanda Sarga 117 and 119 in the Valmiki Ramayana.

From Sarga 117 of Yuddha Kanda,

> ततो वैश्रवणो राजा यमश्च पृभिः सह |
>   सहस्राक्षश्च देवेशो वरुणश्च जलेश्वरः || ६-११७-२
>   षड्र्धनयनः **श्रीमान् महादेवो वृषध्वजः** |
>   कर्ता सर्वस्य लोकस्य ब्रह्मा ब्रह्मविदां वरः || ६-११७-३
>   एते सर्वे समागम्य विमानैः सूर्यसंनिभैः |
>   आगम्य नगरीं लङ्कामभिजग्मुश्च राघवम् || ६-११७-४
>
> Thereupon, Kubera the King of Yakshas, Yama the lord of death together with the deceased ancestors, Indra the lord of celestials Varuna the lord of waters,** the illustrious Shiva the great deity who bears the device of a bull as his banner and having three eyes**, Brahma the creator of all the worlds and the best among the knowers of sacred knowledge all these together reaching the City of Lanka in aerial cars, shining like the sun approached Rama. [[6-117-2]](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddhasans117.htm#Verse2)
>
> ततः सहस्ताभरणान् प्रगृह्य विपुलान् भुजान् |
>   अब्रुवंस्त्रिदशश्रेष्ठा राघवं प्राञ्जलिं स्थितम् || ६-११७-५
>
> Lifting their long arms, their hands decked with ornaments, those excellent gods thereupon, spoke (as follows) to Rama who stood there, making a respectful salutation to them with his folded hands. [[6-117-5]](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga117/yuddhasans117.htm#Verse5)

So all the devatas appeared before Sri Rama after Ravana was killed and agni Pariksha was done for Sita.

For the statement of Shiva praising Sri Rama:

Chinna Jeeyar swami is probably referring to this statement where Shiva praises as the saviour of the wise and punisher of the wicked. From Sarga 119,

> पुष्कराक्ष महाबाहो महावक्षः परन्तप |
>   दिष्ट्या कृतमिदं कर्म त्वया शस्त्रभृतां वर || ६-११९-२
>
> O lotus-eyed, long-armed, broad-chested, **annihilator of enemies and excellent among those upholding the cause of virtue**! Thank heaven! You accomplished this task.  [[6-119-2]](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga119/yuddhasans119.htm#Verse2)

Ravana is indeed wicked. So, this statement is also right.

So, statement has scriptural basis. As a suggestion, the complete article is worth reading where Swamiji says that one can worship Lord Shiva and should not spread wrong stories about incarnation of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: the jeeyar swami cannot help showing siva-hatred every chance he gets  "All the devathas appeared before Rama and one among was Lord Siva" is a disrespectful paraphrasing of "hereupon, Kubera the King of Yakshas, Yama the lord of death together with the deceased ancestors, Indra the lord of celestials Varuna the lord of waters, the illustrious Shiva the great deity who bears the device of a bull as his banner and having three eyes".  by the way this destroys a bit of vaishnavite siva-hatred (mahadeva worshiped by rama=varuna) - here varuna is varuna and mahadeva is siva.

Comment: BTW, it's [sarga 105](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDuiy.jpg) in the CE of VR.

Comment: @SK Both are totally different shlokas you are talking about. This verse has totally different context. Some person has posted a question to Chinna Jeeyar Swami that persons worshipping Shiva will be happy and those who are worshipping Vishnu are in troubles and sorrows. Why? To this HH Swamiji replied by saying the above. Many devatas came and praised Vishnu, one of them is Shiva. It is totally fine. In the end, they said that Worship your own and respect all. I don't see any hatred in this statement.

Comment: @SK There is no mention in the Ramayana that Rama worhsipped Shivalingam and consecrated Rameshwara lingam. Mahadeva is Varuna, Lord of waters. In the previous and next verses, he talks about Varuna and sea god only. In the whole chapter, all the events in that chapter are present in Valmiki Ramayana only but Rama worshipping Shivalingam is not. So, that is a correct statement that Rama didn't wirship Shiva Lingam at Rameshwaram. Don't spread hatred towards Shiva and Vishnu by misinterpreting and cherry picking verses.

Comment: even after I point out varuna = varuna and mahadeva=siva in the same verse (or succeeding verses) - it is clear that nothing will penetrate the hatred vaishnavite have on this topic.

Comment: "Many devatas came and praised Vishnu, one of them is Shiva."  no evidence yet for this.  As far as I know, Siva only calls him Dasaratha's son and a human hero who accomplished something great..  I added the sentence I objected to - no evidence that siva thought Rama was an incarnation.  @Sarvabhouma

Comment: @SK VR appears to be written or modified later to suit Vaishnavism. You should't be looking for verses praising Shiva in there. You won't find them.

Comment: @sv. Ramayana is the story of Rama. You will find story of Rama only. Not about Shiva, Brahma or not even detailed story of Lakshmana. It is not modified or anything to suit a sect's ideas.  According to you, are Shiva Purana, Linga Purana modified later to suit Shaivism? It looks like it.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Ramayana and Mahabharata are Ithihasas. They are not Vaishnava Scriptures. Some people even say Bhagavadgita is Vaishnava scripture, which is not at all true.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks. At least you know that searching verses praising one God in itihasas is not a wise thing. For Bhagavad Gita being Pancharatra scripture, there is more than one answer written by Keshav. I know that many (not some) will say they are interpolations. Then I can just leave a smile at them.

Answer (score 2):

jeeyar forgets to mention that Siva said this as the supreme lord to a human:

> एतच्छ्रुत्वा शुभं वाक्यं राघवेण सुभाषितम् |
>   
>   इदं शुभतरं वाक्यं व्याजहार महेश्वरः || ६-११९-१
>   
>   Hearing the auspicious words thus spoken by Rama, Lord Shiva the Supreme Lord thereupon delivered the following still more beautiful speech:
>
> पुष्कराक्ष महाबाहो महावक्षः परन्तप |
>   
>   दिष्ट्या कृतमिदं कर्म त्वया शस्त्रभृतां वर || ६-११९-२
>   
>   "O lotus-eyed, long-armed, broad-chested, annihilator of enemies and excellent among those upholding the cause of virtue! Thank heaven! You accomplished this task."
>
> दिष्ट्या सर्वस्य लोकस्य प्रवृद्धं दारुणं तमः |
>   
>   अपावृत्तं त्वया सङ्ख्ये राम रावणजं भयम् || ६-११९-३
>   
>   "Fortunately has the fear born of Ravana - which increased the severe darkness on the entire world has been removed by you, on the battle-field, O Rama!"
>
> आश्वास्य भरतं दीनं कौसल्यां च यशस्विनीम् |
>    
>   कैकेयीं च सुमित्रां च दृष्ट्वा लक्ष्मणमातरम् || ६-११९-४
>    
>   प्राप्य राज्यमयोध्यायां नन्दयित्वा सुहृज्जनम् |
>   इक्ष्वाकूणां कुले वंशं स्थापयित्वा महाबल || ६-११९-५
>    
>   इष्ट्वा तुरगमेधेन प्राप्य चानुत्तमं यशः |
>   ब्राह्मणेभ्यो धनं दत्त्वा त्रिदिवं गन्तुमर्हसि || ६-११९-६
>   
>   "You are fit to go to the heaven, by comforting the depressed Bharata and the illustrious Kausalya as well as seeing Kaikeyi and Sumitra, the mother of Lakshmana having got the sovereignty of Ayodhya, bringing delight to your friends, stabilizing the back-bone in the race of Ikshvaku, getting excellent glory by performing a horse-sacrifice and by granting riches to Brahmanas."

You don't tell Vishnu that he would go to heaven - this is a strong indication that Rama was human in the Ramayana and his being an avatara was grafted on the story later.

For Jeeyar to say "Lord Siva also several occasions sought the help of these incarnations.", is a totally wrong description of the supreme Lord Siva congratulating a human on accomplishing a heroic task.

Comment: You should not develop any kind of hatred towards Lord Rama. He was of course human, but he was divine due to austerities, righteousness etc. We're not an iota of the great personality.

Comment: The Chapter 117 of Yuddhakhanda in the Valmiki Ramayana clearly mentions Sri Ram was the Sriman Narayana Himself. So don't cherrypick verses to show Ram to be a normal human being.

Comment: You forgot to read the previous sarga where Brahma and all the devatas praise Rama to be Vishnu, the purusha. So, don't cherry pick verses to show your point and show the supremacy of one God.

Comment: Your question is asking scriptural mention of the statement made by Chinna Jeeyar swami. But in the answer you are not addressing the question at all. This is not an answer.

Comment: Jeeyar Swami didn't say that Shiva asked for help in the Ramayana. Occasions asked for help are there in other puranas. This is still not an answer.